# Stacking implicits conversions

Tags: scala, future, functor

I'm trying to make my use of futures as lightweight as possible.

Here is my current test code :

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.Failure
import scala.util.Success

object Test1 extends App {

  def lift[A](a: A): Future[A] = Future { a }

  def ap[A, B](fct: Future[A => B], param: Future[A]): Future[B] =
    for {
      c <- param
      o <- fct
    } yield (o(c))

  implicit def valToFuture[A](elem: A): Future[A] = lift(elem)
  implicit class FutureInfix[A, B](val x: Future[A => B]) extends AnyVal {
    def <*>(that: Future[A]) = ap(this.x, that)
  }

  val plus1: Int => Int = (x: Int) => x + 1
  val cst1: Int = 1

  val extracted: Future[Int] = ap(plus1, cst1)
  val extracted2: Future[Int] = lift(plus1) <*> lift(cst1)
  val extracted3: Future[Int] = plus1 <*> cst
  /*
   * - value <*> is not a member of Int ⇒ Int
   * - not found: value cst
   */
}
```

extracted and extracted2 are working but are each using only one of the two implicit conversion I've defined.

extracted3 is what I am aiming at, implicitly lifting plus and cst1 to Future[X] values and converting  `a <*> b` to `ap(a,b)`. But the compiler does not seems to agree with me.

Is what i'm trying to achieve possible ? If so, what do I have to change to make it works ?

PS : This i kind of inspired from what I've seen using haskell.

Comment: `cst` is supposed to be undefined?

Comment: no, you cannot chain 2 implicit conversions at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're bumping up against the "one at a time" rule.

From [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html), (1st edition):

> **One-at-a-time Rule**: Only one implicit is tried. The compiler will
>   never rewrite x + y to convert1(convert2(x)) + y. Doing so would cause
>   compile times to increase dramatically on erroneous code, and it would
>   increase the difference between what the programmer writes and what
>   the program actually does. For sanity's sake, the compiler does not
>   insert further implicit conversions when it is already in the middle
>   of trying another implicit.

---

As @tkachuko has pointed out, there likely is a work-around for this limitation using implicit parameters, but one simple solution is to split `FutureInfix` into two parts.

```
implicit class FromFutureInfix[A, B](x: Future[A => B]) {
  def <*>(that: Future[A]) = ap(x, that)
}
implicit class ToFutureInfix[A, B](x: A => B) {
  def <*>(that: A) = ap(x, that)
}
```

Comment: But still it looks like target can be achieved with implicit def chaining: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/chaining-implicits.html